# How do I select and count records less than 1 year old?

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, date, sqflite

I'm using sqflite in my Flutter application. In this example, date is the actual date(10.06.2021) and DATUM is the datafield in the DB.

```
var x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Shisha_table WHERE YEAR('+date+') - YEAR(DATUM) = 1');
int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
return count;
```

I keep getting this syntax error:

> E/SQLiteLog(30657): (1) near ".2021": syntax error in "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Shisha_table WHERE (YEAR(10.06.2021) - YEAR(DATUM)) = 1"

Comment: Very confusing.  SQLite doesn't have a `year()` function.

Comment: Is there any other Function that i can use in sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `YEAR()` function in SQLite.

The logic of your code can be written by extracting the year of a date with the use of the function `strftime()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Shisha_table 
WHERE strftime('%Y', CURRENT_DATE) - strftime('%Y', DATUM) <= 1
```

Or, if you want the rows from the same date in last year untill today:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Shisha_table 
WHERE DATUM >= date(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 year')
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try it out later

Comment: im still getting a syntax error: `E/SQLiteLog(32434): (1) near ".2020": syntax error in "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Shisha_table WHERE strftime('%Y',03.06.2020) - strftime('%Y', DATUM) <= 1"` My Code: `await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Shisha_table WHERE strftime(\'%Y\','+ currentdate+') - strftime(\'%Y\', DATUM) <= 1');`

Comment: @Dankel as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9f4909da0203e58fe051576c9ee4448b the queries are syntactically correct. Note that you must store the dates in ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Instead of `03.06.2020` you must have `'2020-06-03'`.

Comment: @Dankel Also, use `CURRENT_DATE` and not `currentdate`

Comment: is it not possible to use it in a DD-MM-YYYY ? we use this ISO Format in Europa

Comment: @Dankel no. SQLite's functions work only with TEXT dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` or integer dates as unixepoch.

Comment: sorry for my late answers, Thanks! its working. U know a way how do the same with rows from the last Month and also with rows from the last Week.

Comment: @Dankel with `WHERE DATUM >= date(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 month')` and `WHERE DATUM >= date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day')`